# How to pass parameter to html file from python script and get the output

Tags: javascript, python, html, parameter-passing

I have a python file **source.py** and a html file **calculate.html**. Purpose of the html file to return a number which is 2 times of a given number. The content of the html file is the following:

```
   <html>
     <body>
       <script>
       function multiply_By_2()
       {
         var output = <Input number> * 2; // I want to return this output back to the source.py
       }
       </script>
     </body>
  </html>
```

Now, I want to call this calculate.html file from **source.py** by passing a number, and get the return value, something like this:

```
get_return_value = call (<calculate.html>, input_number=9)
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: But why? You could simply have the calculation as a Python function. HTML isn't really meant to be used this way.

Comment: HTML requires a whole engine to parse it. Scripts within that HTML may require a second engine to parse and invoke them. You would need to run such engines to read the HTML file. First you need to add some XMLHttpRequest/whatever in your `<script>` to pass the result to some port e.g. `localhost:3003`, then you would need to host the file on another port, e.g. `3002`, have python listen for feedback on `localhost:3003` and invoke the engines to load the HTML from `localhost:3002`. So this requires massive dependencies.

Alternatively, transcribe the function from _JavaScript_ to _Python_ :)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to pass the number in the URL and have javascript extract it for you:
`calculate.html?number=9`

Javascript can return you the parameters in a string with `location.search`.
It will return 
`?number=9`
 Next, you have to trim the string so that only the number will remain and then pass it to your function.

However, you're making it difficult for yourself. I don't see why you couldn't just have a multiply function in your python code.